# Layering <div></div>

Tags: css, html, layer

Hi all I have reached a brick wall with google :)

I am trying to layer one div (#menubar) over another (#background)

My html is. . . . .

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="menubar"></div>
```

And my CSS is. . . .

```
#background {
Width:98%;
height:1000px;
position: relative;
background-color:#878787;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#003366;
border-width:10px;
z-index:1;
}

#menubar {
top:5;
left:0;
Width:50px;
height:50px;
position:relative;
z-index:2;
background-color:#CCCC99;
}
```

Any ideas why its not working ? 
Thanks

Ps new to html so sorry is it's a silly question

Here is a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Tz/

Comment: use position:absolute, not position:relative.

Comment: On a side note, don't forget to use units. `top:5;
left:0;` don't mean anything without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving it an absolute position?
Edit your code as:

```
#background {
Width:98%;
height:1000px;
position: relative;
background-color:#878787;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#003366;
border-width:10px;
z-index:1;
}

#menubar {
top:5;
left:0;
Width:50px;
height:50px;
position:relative;
z-index:2;
background-color:#CCCC99;
}
```

And also check this link for more: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: Sorted, Thanks I must have missed the px when I tried position absolute

Comment: Yah maybe that was an issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
#background { 
position:absolute;
 }
```

The bottom layer needs position:absolute.

Answer (score 0):

use position: absolute for your menubar:

```
#background {
Width:98%;
height:1000px;
position: relative;
background-color:#878787;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#003366;
border-width:10px;
z-index:1;
}

#menubar {
top:5px; /* --- Specify with either %, px's, or em --- */
left:0;  /* --- Specify with either %, px's, or em --- */
Width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
background-color:#CCCC99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
#background {
    Width:98%;
    height:1000px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#878787;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#003366;
    border-width:10px;
    z-index:1;
}
#menubar {
    top:5px;
    left:0;
    Width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:#CCCC99;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pv3Tz/1/